# Error building helloWorld application using xamarin.Forms

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to run the hello forms application that visual studio creates when you select the Xamarin.Forms template.But I am getting lots of errors when I try to start the android version of the application.Here are some of the errors that I get :

```
 Activate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object[])
 in mono.android.TypeManager cannot be applied to
 (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,md5d4dd78677dce656d5db26c85a3743ef3.CarouselPageAdapter,java.lang.Object[])
 mono.android.TypeManager.Activate
 ("Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CarouselPageAdapter,
 Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=1.3.3.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] { });

 cannot find symbol symbol : method getClass() location: class
 md5d4dd78677dce656d5db26c85a3743ef3.CarouselPageAdapter if (getClass
 () == CarouselPageAdapter.class)

 package android.support.v4.content.Loader does not exist
 android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener
```

all the other errors(total of 30) are like the errors above only with different class names.I already updated the support library from the android sdk manager but I still get these errors.What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself finally
what I did was to download [android_m2repository_r10](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r10.zip) from google server and extract it in

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\

uninstalled jdk 6 from my pc, reinstalled jdk7, rebooted my pc and then rebuilt my project and now all the errors are gone

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your **Android** project target above **API16**